# Assign tinymce to text formats

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, installation-profiles

Just to start with I am trying to do this in code (installation profile), not in Drupal itself.

In my installation profile I create three text formats. Thanks to the drush make file tinymce is also automaticly installed. Now wysiwyg gives you the option to assign the editor to a text format. See image below how the option looks in Drupal.

[image: tinymce]

Now I am wondering how I could change the 'No editor' to 'TinyMCE' in my installtion profile. After changing the option in drupal itself then the database changes to: (see image below)

[image: tinymce_db]

What is the right way to do this and how can I change these module settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the WYSIWYG modules' code when saving the form, it implements:

```
db_merge('wysiwyg')
  ->key(array('format' => 'full_html'))
  ->fields(array(
    'editor' => 'tinymce',
  ))
  ->execute();
```

So that's what I suspect you'll need to put into your install profile

Comment: Thanks, and you have any idea how to change settings, such as which button should be enabled in tinymce? EDIT: Never mind got it fixed, just copied the code from the database and added it to the fields like you did above.